# How to detect which Android apps use its permission to send SMS messages?

Tags: android, sms, phone-number, android-permissions

Some Android apps use its permission to send SMS to a phone number to extract money from the user.

How to detect which Android apps use its permission to send SMS messages?

Comment: Are you wanting to find out if an app has permission to send SMS messages, or if an app has *used* that permission?

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ApplicationInfo> Apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for ( ApplicationInfo app : Apps ) {
    // Info we can fetch app.packageName,app.uid, app.sourceDir

    // for Permissions:
    StringBuffer permissions = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(app.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if ( requestedPermissions != null ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i] + "\n");
            }

            // fetch  permissions
        }
    }
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```